# WPF view similar to MS Word 2010

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, layout, grid

I'm trying to create a document layout similar to the display in Word 2010 when a document is open.  Basically I want to be able to have a gray background, with a white grid in the center of it, so that some of the gray is left as a margin around the grid.  I've made the external grid with a background of gray, and then placed another grid inside that with a background of white.  Yet the only thing that shows white on the inner grid are the textboxes inside it, the portions between the textboxes shows the gray from the outer grid.  I've tried changing the outer grid to a canvas as well, but this made no difference either.  Does anybody know of a way to get this to work?

Here's most of the code, I had to remove some of the details like individual textboxes in order to fit under the 30k character limit.  Based on the first response I got, I'm thinking the issue may be somewhere higher up, in the window setup possibly, but I'm not seeing it if it is.  The visibility property is there because I have several buttons for selecting various grids to be displayed, similar to a tab control.  When a button is clicked, it sets Visibility on the correct grid to Visible, and the others to collapsed.

```
<Window x:Class="Dialer_Team_Record_Keeping.MainWindow"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Dialer_Team_Record_Keeping"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="550" Width="0" FontSize="14" MinWidth="610">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:AddListRecordsConverter x:Key="AddListRecordsConverter" />
    <local:SubtractListRecordsConverter x:Key="SubtractListRecordsConverter" />
    <local:AverageListRecordsConverter x:Key="AverageListRecordsConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <StackPanel x:Name="toolbar" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="Auto" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button x:Name="sendWrap" Content="Send Wrap" Height="30" Margin="2,2,4,2" Padding="8,0,8,0" Click="sendWrap_Click" />
        <Button x:Name="sendEmail" Content="Send Email" Height="30" Margin="0,2,4,2" Padding="8,0,8,0" Click="sendEmail_Click" />
        <Button x:Name="importData" Content="Import Data" Height="30" Margin="0,2,4,2" Padding="8,0,8,0" Click="importData_Click" />
        <Button x:Name="saveData" Content="Save Data" Height="30" Margin="0,2,4,2" Padding="8,0,8,0" Click="saveData_Click" />
        <Button x:Name="currentWindowSize" Content="Show Window Size" Height="30" Margin="0,2,4,2" Padding="8,0,8,0"  Background="Orange" Click="currentWindowSize_Click" />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel x:Name="formSelector" DockPanel.Dock="Left" >
        <Button x:Name="showEarlyStage" Content="ES" Margin="5,5,5,2.5" Padding="5" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold" Width="Auto" Height="{Binding ElementName=showEarlyStage, Path=ActualWidth}" ToolTip="Early Stage" Click="showEarlyStage_Click" >
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="showLateStage" Content="LS" Margin="5,2.5" Padding="5" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold" Width="Auto" Height="{Binding ElementName=showEarlyStage, Path=ActualWidth}" ToolTip="Late Stage" Click="showLateStage_Click">                
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="showLossMit" Content="LM" Margin="5,2.5" Padding="5" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold" Width="Auto" Height="{Binding ElementName=showEarlyStage, Path=ActualWidth}" ToolTip="Loss Mitigation" Click="showLossMit_Click" >
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="showWeekend" Content="WE" Margin="5,2.5" Padding="5" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold" Width="Auto" Height="{Binding ElementName=showEarlyStage, Path=ActualWidth}" ToolTip="Weekend" Click="showWeekend_Click">
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
    <Grid Background="Gray">
        <Grid x:Name="dialerTeamCanvas" Visibility="Visible" Background="White">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <DatePicker x:Name="dialerRecordsSelect" Grid.Row="0" Width="110" Margin="0,2,0,2" KeyDown="dialerRecordsSelect_KeyDown" SelectedDateChanged="dialerRecordsSelect_SelectedDateChanged" />
                <DataGrid x:Name="dialerRecordsDataGrid" Grid.Row="1" ColumnWidth="Auto" ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource datagridCenterHeaderStyle}" CellStyle="{StaticResource datagridCenterCellStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="5,5,5,5" AutoGenerateColumns="True" AutoGeneratingColumn="dialerRecordsDataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn" RowHeaderWidth="0" />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Border>
            <Canvas x:Name="earlyStageCanvas" Visibility="Collapsed" >
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                <Grid x:Name="esGrid" DockPanel.Dock="Left">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="30" x:Name="esGridRowZero" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" x:Name="esGridRowOne" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" x:Name="esGridRowTwo" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <DatePicker x:Name="recordDateES" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,5,0,5" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" SelectedDateChanged="recordDateES_SelectedDateChanged" />
                    <Label Content="Records" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" />
                    <Label Content="Dials" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" />
                    <Label Content="Saturation" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" />
                    <TextBlock Text="% of Total Callables" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="3" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="60" />
                    <TextBlock Text="% of Accounts Worked" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="3" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="60" />
                    <Label Content="Pass %" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" />
                    <Label Content="Pass %" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" />
                    <!--<Label Content="Records" Grid.Column="8" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" />
                <Label Content="Dials" Grid.Column="9" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" />
                <Label Content="Saturation" Grid.Column="10" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" />
                <TextBlock Text="% of Total Callables" Grid.Column="11" Grid.Row="3" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="60" />
                <TextBlock Text="% of Accounts Worked" Grid.Column="12" Grid.Row="3" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="60"/>
                <Label Content="Pass %" Grid.Column="13" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" />
                <TextBlock Text="% of Accounts Worked" Grid.Column="7" Grid.Row="3" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="60"/>
                <Label Content="Pass %" Grid.Column="8" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" />
                <TextBlock Text="% of Accounts Worked" Grid.Column="9" Grid.Row="3" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="60"/>
                <Label Content="Pass %" Grid.Column="10" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" /> -->
                    <Label Content="Mass Cell" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" />
                    <Label Content="MI Cell" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="5" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" />
                    <Label Content="All" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="6" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" />
                    <Label Content="Mass" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="9" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" />
                    <Label Content="NH" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="10" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" />
                    <Label Content="Non-Cont" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="11" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" />
                    <Label Content="OR" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="12" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" />
                    <Label Content="Combined" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="13" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" FontWeight="Bold" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="massCellRecords" Style="{StaticResource dataEntryTextBox}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" LostFocus="massCellRecords_LostFocus" GotFocus="SelectAllOnFocus_GotFocus" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="massCellDials" Style="{StaticResource dataEntryTextBox}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4" LostFocus="massCellDials_LostFocus" GotFocus="SelectAllOnFocus_GotFocus" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="massCellSaturation" Style="{StaticResource readOnlyTextBox}" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="4" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="massCellPercentTotal" Style="{StaticResource readOnlyTextBox}" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="4" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="massCellPercentWorked" Style="{StaticResource dataEntryTextBox}" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="4" LostFocus="massCellPercentWorked_LostFocus" GotFocus="SelectAllOnFocus_GotFocus" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="massCellPassPercent" Style="{StaticResource readOnlyTextBox}" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="4" Text="0.0" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="miCellRecords" Style="{StaticResource dataEntryTextBox}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" GotFocus="SelectAllOnFocus_GotFocus" LostFocus="miCellRecords_LostFocus" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="miCellDials" Style="{StaticResource dataEntryTextBox}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="5" LostFocus="miCellDials_LostFocus" GotFocus="SelectAllOnFocus_GotFocus" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="miCellSaturation" Style="{StaticResource readOnlyTextBox}" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="5" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="miCellPercentTotal" Style="{StaticResource readOnlyTextBox}" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="5" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="miCellPercentWorked" Style="{StaticResource dataEntryTextBox}" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="5" GotFocus="SelectAllOnFocus_GotFocus" LostFocus="miCellPercentWorked_LostFocus" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="miCellPassPercent" Style="{StaticResource readOnlyTextBox}" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="5" Text="0.0" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="allRecords" Style="{StaticResource dataEntryTextBox}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6" GotFocus="SelectAllOnFocus_GotFocus" LostFocus="allRecords_LostFocus" />
                    <!-- Event members from TextBox allRecords
                     GotFocus="SelectAllOnFocus_GotFocus" LostFocus="allRecords_LostFocus"
                    -->
                    <TextBox x:Name="allDials" Style="{StaticResource readOnlyTextBox}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="6" LostFocus="allDials_LostFocus" GotFocus="SelectAllOnFocus_GotFocus">
                        <TextBox.Text>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource AddListRecordsConverter}">
                                <Binding ElementName="allDialsOne" Path="Text" Mode="OneWay" />
                                <Binding ElementName="allDialsTwo" Path="Text" Mode="OneWay" />
                                <Binding ElementName="allDialsThree" Path="Text" Mode="OneWay" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </TextBox.Text>
                    </TextBox>
                    <TextBox x:Name="allSaturation" Style="{StaticResource readOnlyTextBox}" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="6">
                        <TextBox.Text>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource AddListRecordsConverter}">
                                <Binding ElementName="allSaturationOne" Path="Text" Mode="OneWay" />
                                <Binding ElementName="allSaturationTwo" Path="Text" Mode="OneWay" />
                                <Binding ElementName="allSaturationThree" Path="Text" Mode="OneWay" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </TextBox.Text>
                    </TextBox>
                    <TextBox x:Name="allPercentTotal" Style="{StaticResource readOnlyTextBox}" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="6" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="allPercentWorked" Style="{StaticResource readOnlyTextBox}" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="6" GotFocus="SelectAllOnFocus_GotFocus" LostFocus="allPercentWorked_LostFocus" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="allPassPercent" Style="{StaticResource readOnlyTextBox}" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="6" Text="0.0" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="massRecords" Style="{StaticResource dataEntryTextBox}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="9" GotFocus="SelectAllOnFocus_GotFocus" LostFocus="massRecords_LostFocus" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="massDials" Style="{StaticResource dataEntryTextBox}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="9" GotFocus="SelectAllOnFocus_GotFocus" LostFocus="massDials_LostFocus" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="massSaturation" Style="{StaticResource readOnlyTextBox}" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="9" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="massPercentTotal" Style="{StaticResource readOnlyTextBox}" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="9" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="massPercentWorked" Style="{StaticResource dataEntryTextBox}" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="9" GotFocus="SelectAllOnFocus_GotFocus" LostFocus="massPercentWorked_LostFocus" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="massPassPercent" Style="{StaticResource readOnlyTextBox}" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="9" Text="0.0" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="nhRecords" Style="{StaticResource dataEntryTextBox}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="10" GotFocus="SelectAllOnFocus_GotFocus" LostFocus="nhRecords_LostFocus" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="nhDials" Style="{StaticResource dataEntryTextBox}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="10" GotFocus="SelectAllOnFocus_GotFocus" LostFocus="nhDials_LostFocus" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="nhSaturation" Style="{StaticResource readOnlyTextBox}" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="10" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="nhPercentTotal" Style="{StaticResource readOnlyTextBox}" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="10" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="nhPercentWorked" Style="{StaticResource dataEntryTextBox}" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="10" GotFocus="SelectAllOnFocus_GotFocus" LostFocus="nhPercentWorked_LostFocus" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="nhPassPercent" Style="{StaticResource readOnlyTextBox}" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="10" Text="0.0" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="nonContRecords" Style="{StaticResource dataEntryTextBox}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="11" GotFocus="SelectAllOnFocus_GotFocus" LostFocus="nonContRecords_LostFocus" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="nonContDials" Style="{StaticResource dataEntryTextBox}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="11" GotFocus="SelectAllOnFocus_GotFocus" LostFocus="nonContDials_LostFocus" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="nonContSaturation" Style="{StaticResource readOnlyTextBox}" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="11" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="nonContPercentTotal" Style="{StaticResource readOnlyTextBox}" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="11" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="nonContPercentWorked" Style="{StaticResource dataEntryTextBox}" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="11" GotFocus="SelectAllOnFocus_GotFocus" LostFocus="nonContPercentWorked_LostFocus" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="nonContPassPercent" Style="{StaticResource readOnlyTextBox}" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="11" Text="0.0" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="orRecords" Style="{StaticResource dataEntryTextBox}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="12" GotFocus="SelectAllOnFocus_GotFocus" LostFocus="orRecords_LostFocus" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="orDials" Style="{StaticResource dataEntryTextBox}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="12" GotFocus="SelectAllOnFocus_GotFocus" LostFocus="orDials_LostFocus" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="orSaturation" Style="{StaticResource readOnlyTextBox}" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="12" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="orPercentTotal" Style="{StaticResource readOnlyTextBox}" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="12" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="orPercentWorked" Style="{StaticResource dataEntryTextBox}" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="12" GotFocus="SelectAllOnFocus_GotFocus" LostFocus="orPercentWorked_LostFocus" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="orPassPercent" Style="{StaticResource readOnlyTextBox}" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="12" Text="0.0" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="combinedRecords" Style="{StaticResource readOnlyTextBox}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="13">
                        <TextBox.Text>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource AddListRecordsConverter}">
                                <Binding ElementName="massCellRecords" Path="Text" Mode="OneWay" />
                                <Binding ElementName="miCellRecords" Path="Text" Mode="OneWay" />
                                <Binding ElementName="allRecords" Path="Text" Mode="OneWay" />
                                <Binding ElementName="massRecords" Path="Text" Mode="OneWay" />
                                <Binding ElementName="nhRecords" Path="Text" Mode="OneWay" />
                                <Binding ElementName="nonContRecords" Path="Text" Mode="OneWay" />
                                <Binding ElementName="orRecords" Path="Text" Mode="OneWay" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </TextBox.Text>
                    </TextBox>
                    <TextBox x:Name="combinedDials" Style="{StaticResource readOnlyTextBox}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="13">
                        <TextBox.Text>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource AddListRecordsConverter}">
                                <Binding ElementName="massCellDials" Path="Text" Mode="OneWay" />
                                <Binding ElementName="miCellDials" Path="Text" Mode="OneWay" />
                                <Binding ElementName="allDialsOne" Path="Text" Mode="OneWay" />
                                <Binding ElementName="allDialsTwo" Path="Text" Mode="OneWay" />
                                <Binding ElementName="allDialsThree" Path="Text" Mode="OneWay" />
                                <Binding ElementName="massDials" Path="Text" Mode="OneWay" />
                                <Binding ElementName="nhDials" Path="Text" Mode="OneWay" />
                                <Binding ElementName="nonContDials" Path="Text" Mode="OneWay" />
                                <Binding ElementName="orDials" Path="Text" Mode="OneWay" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </TextBox.Text>
                    </TextBox>
                    <TextBox x:Name="combinedSaturation" Style="{StaticResource readOnlyTextBox}" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="13" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="combinedPassPercent" Style="{StaticResource readOnlyTextBox}" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="13">
                        <TextBox.Text>                                
                        </TextBox.Text>
                    </TextBox>
                    <!--<TextBox x:Name="combinedPercentWorkedTwo" Style="{StaticResource readOnlyTextBox}" Grid.Column="7" Grid.Row="13"  />-->
                    <!--<TextBox x:Name="combinedPercentWorkedThree" Style="{StaticResource readOnlyTextBox}" Grid.Column="9" Grid.Row="13"  /> -->
                </Grid>
                <Expander x:Name="allListExpander" Background="LightYellow" DockPanel.Dock="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right" ExpandDirection="Right" IsExpanded="False" Height="{Binding ElementName=esGrid, Path=ActualHeight}" Collapsed="allListExpander_OnCollapsed" Expanded="AllListExpander_OnExpanded">
                    <Expander.Header>
                        <TextBlock Text="All List Detail" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="90"></RotateTransform>
                            </TextBlock.LayoutTransform></TextBlock>
                    </Expander.Header>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=esGridRowZero, Path=ActualHeight}" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=esGridRowOne, Path=ActualHeight}" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=esGridRowTwo, Path=ActualHeight}" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    </Grid>
                </Expander>
            </DockPanel>
        </Canvas>
        </Border>
        <Canvas x:Name="lateStageCanvas" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas x:Name="lossMitCanvas" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas x:Name="weekendCanvas" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>                    
            </Grid>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: Doesn't look like your sample is demonstrating the problem. When I set the inner grid Visibility to Visible and put a margin on it, I get the following: http://imgur.com/4NX5BRX

Comment: That's really odd, as I tried making that one that I posted visible to check it (I realized after you posted the picture that I hadn't actually tried with that canvas yet), but no difference.  I get it to stretch, but not to show the grey border.  I'm actually thinking now that it may be somewhere in the Window or DockPanel setup itself, I just can't figure out where.

Comment: So apparently never mind, now it seems to work fine.  I can't figure out anything I did differently, other than adding a Button for the `dialerTeamCanvas` that toggles the visibility the same as the others did, but now it seems to work perfectly.  Thanks @WasGoodDone for looking at it, and possibly for causing me to do something to correct it unconsciously.  :)